# How to make my animation more smooth/fluid in Xamarin.Ios (C#,Xaml)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, width, translation

I try to make a automatic scroll for a label who cannot fit totally fit in a Box View, so I use two list of char, one visible and the other not and switch char from one to other, that wasn't smooth at all cause my label jump each to the left in function of the size of the char who disappear so I use Translation X to jump to the right in function of the size of the char who disappear and TranslationTo to make the jump slow and control, the fact is I can't know precisely the size in pixel of the char, so I put value myself for now, do you have an idea of how I could know the size in pixel or if you have another idea to make my label scroll automatically.

I already try width, the result was always -1, I already try to call TextRenderer.MesureText but can't use it and I already try graphics.MeasureString but System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform, maybe I didn't use them right, if you can help me I would really appreciate.

```
private async void StartAnimation3()
    {
        List<char> firstQueue = new List<char>();         //to stock what I d'ont display
        List<char> secondQueue = new List<char>();          //visible one 

        int initialX = (int)metroLabel.TranslationX; 
        int sizeStringVisble = 60;                                 //width of label I can display I suppose it's close to 60 chars
        firstQueue.AddRange(new char[] { ' ', '/', ' ' }); 
        string texteComplet = "Température bureau 20°C - 15000 lumens - Volets a 80%";      //my text

        foreach (char s in texteComplet)     //I fill my lists
        {
            if (secondQueue.Count < sizeStringVisble)
            { 
                secondQueue.Add(s);
            }
            else
            {
                firstQueue.Add(s);
            }  
        }
        
        if (secondQueue.Count < sizeStringVisble)   //fill them with space to reach the width of my label 
        {
            int nbEspace = sizeStringVisble - (secondQueue.Count);
            for (int i= 0; i < nbEspace; i++)
            {
                secondQueue.Add(' ');
            }
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (secondQueue.Count < sizeStringVisble)    //I switch my chars
            {

                if (secondQueue.Count != 0)
                {
                    char s = secondQueue[0];
                    secondQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                    firstQueue.Add(s);
                }

                if (firstQueue.Count != 0)
                {
                    char s = firstQueue[0];
                    firstQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                    secondQueue.Add(s);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                char s = secondQueue[0];
                secondQueue.RemoveAt(0);
                firstQueue.Add(s);

            }


            if (firstQueue.Last() == ' ' || firstQueue.Last() == '/' || firstQueue.Last() == '°') 
            {
                metroLabel.TranslationX += 5;    //I suppose that this type of char are 5 pixels 
                await metroLabel.TranslateTo(initialX, metroLabel.TranslationY, 80);
                
            }
            else if (char.IsUpper(firstQueue.Last()) || firstQueue.Last() == '%')
            {
                metroLabel.TranslationX += 7;     //I suppose that this type of char are 7 pixels
                await metroLabel.TranslateTo(initialX, metroLabel.TranslationY, 175);
            }
            else
            {
                metroLabel.TranslationX += 6;    //I suppose that this type of char are 6 pixels
                await metroLabel.TranslateTo(initialX, metroLabel.TranslationY, 150);
            }

            metroLabel.Text = String.Join("", secondQueue.ToArray());
        }
```

Comment: I am not quite understand. Why not use a scrollview?

Comment: Cause my label have to fit in a Box View and I don't want to interact with it, it has to be automatic.

Comment: How do you put a label in a Box View? BoxView doesn't have a content. Could you show the related xaml code?

Comment: I have a Box View and a Label, that's two separate code lines but the label must not exceed the width of the box, that's why I need to make it scroll automatically, to display all the information.

Comment: So you use the AbsoluteLayout as the outer container?

Comment: Yes, I use an AbsoluteLayout as container.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a ScrollView to wrap the label,

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 10, 400, 50" />
    <ScrollView x:Name="myscroll" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                WidthRequest="400"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 20, AutoSize, AutoSize">
        <Label x:Name="label" Text="long text here......"
           FontSize="24"
           />
    </ScrollView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Because the scrollview can scroll programmatically, you may try using

1.[Scroll an element into view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scroll-an-element-into-view) : this just scroll the label to the end

```
await myscroll.ScrollToAsync(label, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

2.[Scroll a position into view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scroll-a-position-into-view) : this scroll to 150 device-independent units from the top of the ScrollView

```
await myscroll.ScrollToAsync(150, 0, true);
```

to control the scroll of ScrollView.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I cannot make scrollToAsync work (nothing happen even if I change the value inside) but it's giving result with the ScrollView, LayoutBounds and TranslateTo, do you still don't know a way to know the length of a string in pixels for my knowledge?

Comment: I put the label in the scrollview. And the width of scrollview is the same as that of BoxView. If the label is too long to fit the boxview, then use scrolltoasync to scroll the scrollview.

Comment: You could use [Scroll a position into view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scroll-a-position-into-view) or [Scroll an element into view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scroll-an-element-into-view).